# How to enable domain option in Windows 7?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008

How to enable this option Domain?

[Screenshot of the disabled option Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN18S.png)

Here is the IPv4 properties of windows server 2008 R2.

[Screenshot of IPv4 properties of WinServer 2008 R2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlR7e.png)

and also the IPv4 properties of windows 7

[Screenshot of IPv4 properties of Win 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl6uX.png)

Comment: It is possible this question would be better on _Super User_ or _Server Fault_, though I don't post much on either, so I cannot say for sure. However, it is not a programming question, and so is off-topic here.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions (here and elsewhere).